# Moen Bathroom Faucet Cartridge

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, cartridge

## I need to identify the cartridge for a **`MOEN`** sink handle.

I need to know which cartridge to get, so I can purchuse the correct special tool for my sink. It is leaking, and I believe replacing the cartridge will solve this issue. If anyone knows how to go about this I would be greatful, thank you.

> *I will have a picture up when I get home to take one, but while I have the time I thought I would write the question.*

Comment: Step one - call Moen technical support and see if they will send you one for free. Many of their faucets are "guaranteed for life" in residential use.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Gawd damn it I already ordered it. That is really good advice though.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I just got home, and took the faucet apart and found a number on the actual cartridge. It was a 6 digit number on the bottem. I googled the number and a bunch of places selling my faucet popped up. I was able to click on one of the selling sites, and pull the model number from there. The odd thing was that the model number only contained 3 of the digits on the brass fixture that the cartridge goes it. Im taking a picture right now with my I-pad and will edit it in. Hope this helps someone!